# Why are my react icons not functioning properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-icons

attached is the code below for a little app I am making with React Native. I was trying to use react icons but for some reason they are not working and idk why. I imported them and everything and they should be working but I keep getting this error. [image] Does anyone know why my react icons are not functioning properly? Thanks in advance.

```
import { View, Text, SafeAreaView, Image } from 'react-native';
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';

const HomeScreen = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
            navigation.setOptions({
                headerShown: false,
            });
    }, []);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
        <Text className="text-red-500">
            <View className="flex-row pb-3 items-center mx-4 space-x-2">
                <Image
                    source={{
                        url:"https://links.papareact.com/wru",
                    }}
                    className="h-7 w-7 bg-gray-300 p-4 rounded-full"
                />
        
                <View>
                    <Text className="font-bold text-gray-400 text-xs">
                        Deliver Now
                    </Text>
                    <Text className="font-bold text-xl">Current Location
                        <FaBeer />
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

react-icons doesn't work with react native (i think). You need to use react-native-vector-icons (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vector-icons)

Answer (score 0):

you cant use normal react icons since in react native icons can be either an image or can be SVG, so for SVG icons, you need to add `react-native-svg` package.

You should install as @dev404 said https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Also do follow their installation process for both android and ios.

YOu can check the below available icon sets.

[image]

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts